# R error: argument to 'which' is not logical

Tags: r

I have a vector with file names. Several of the files in the vector are repeated with different versions. For example

"ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-3"

"ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-4"

"Cython-0.23.4-x86_64-1"

"Cython-0.29.12-x86_64-1"

"GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-3"

"GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-4"

"LibRaw-0.17.2-x86_64-1"

"LibRaw-0.18.12-x86_64-1"

"M2Crypto-0.23.0-x86_64-1"

"M2Crypto-0.35.2-x86_64-1"

"MPlayer-1.2_20160125-x86_64-3"

"MPlayer-20190418-x86_64-1"

"Mako-1.0.13-x86_64-1"

"ModemManager-1.10.4-x86_64-1"

"ModemManager-1.4.14-x86_64-1"

"NetworkManager-1.18.1-x86_64-1"

"NetworkManager-1.2.2-x86_64-2"

"PyQt-4.11.4-x86_64-1"

"PyQt-4.12.1-x86_64-3"

"QScintilla-2.10.8-x86_64-2"

```
dput(hd1)
c("ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-3", "ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-4", 
"Cython-0.23.4-x86_64-1", "Cython-0.29.12-x86_64-1", "GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-3", 
"GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-4", "LibRaw-0.17.2-x86_64-1",   "LibRaw-0.18.12-x86_64-1", 
"M2Crypto-0.23.0-x86_64-1", "M2Crypto-0.35.2-x86_64-1", "MPlayer-1.2_20160125-x86_64-3", 
"MPlayer-20190418-x86_64-1", "Mako-1.0.13-x86_64-1", "ModemManager-1.10.4-x86_64-1", 
"ModemManager-1.4.14-x86_64-1", "NetworkManager-1.18.1-x86_64-1", 
"NetworkManager-1.2.2-x86_64-2", "PyQt-4.11.4-x86_64-1",    "PyQt-4.12.1-x86_64-3", 
"QScintilla-2.10.8-x86_64-2")
```

I want to make a new vector that only has the newest version of each of the files that appears with multiple versions. For example, the new list would start with

"ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-4"

"Cython-0.29.12-x86_64-1" ...

I made a list of the files that have multiple versions so that I can compare them to list of all files.

```
dput(fix1[1:30])
c("ConsoleKit2", "Cython", "GConf", "LibRaw", "M2Crypto", "MPlayer", 
"ModemManager", "NetworkManager", "PyQt", "QScintilla", "Thunar", 
"a2ps", "a52dec", "aaa_base", "aaa_elflibs", "aaa_terminfo", 
"aalib", "acct", "acl", "acpid", "adwaita-icon-theme", "akonadi", 
"alpine", "alsa-lib", "alsa-oss", "alsa-plugins", "alsa-utils", 
"amarok", "amor", "amp")
```

I wrote a little function to compare the complete list and the list of the files with multiple versions, but I keep getting an error that I don't understand.

The function has several steps and I simplified the function here, because the error occurs early.

```
> ser2 <- function(in1, ... ) {
+ out1 = NULL  #output
+ l1 <- hd1 #list of all files
+ for (i in 1:length(in1 )) {
+ out1[i] = l1[which(grepl(in1[i], l1))][1]  #start to filter the main list by list of dupes
+ }
+ return(out1)
+ }
> 
> 
> ser2(fix1)
Error in which(grepl(in1[i], l1)) : argument to 'which' is not logical
> traceback()
2: which(grepl(in1[i], l1)) at #5
1: ser2(fix1)
```

I don't know why `which(grepl(in1[i], l1))` returns this error when it's inside the function. If I use

`> which(grepl(fix1[2], hd1))
[1] 3 4`

it works fine.

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Slackware 14.2 x86_64 (post 14.2 -current)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_US       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=en_US    LC_MESSAGES=en_US   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 magrittr_1.5   tools_3.6.1    stringi_1.4.3
```

EDIT-I changed the sample function a little after the answer from nograpes. I still get the same error about the argument to `which()` not being logical.

Comment: is ```hd1``` declared in your function?
One think I would try is to print the ```i``` values so as to check the point that the code breaks. Then I would add an if at the beginning of the for loop with a ```browser()```. If the code breaks even for the first iteration I would just add the browser in the for loop to check the values of my variables...

Comment: I added a `print()` statement in the very beginning of the for loop. Turns out my `fix1` list had some NA values that I was not aware of. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't fail in the same way for me. If I run:

```
hd1 <- c("ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-3", "ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-4", 
     "Cython-0.23.4-x86_64-1", "Cython-0.29.12-x86_64-1", "GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-3", 
     "GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-4", "LibRaw-0.17.2-x86_64-1",   "LibRaw-0.18.12-x86_64-1", 
     "M2Crypto-0.23.0-x86_64-1", "M2Crypto-0.35.2-x86_64-1", "MPlayer-1.2_20160125-x86_64-3", 
     "MPlayer-20190418-x86_64-1", "Mako-1.0.13-x86_64-1", "ModemManager-1.10.4-x86_64-1", 
     "ModemManager-1.4.14-x86_64-1", "NetworkManager-1.18.1-x86_64-1", 
     "NetworkManager-1.2.2-x86_64-2", "PyQt-4.11.4-x86_64-1",    "PyQt-4.12.1-x86_64-3", 
     "QScintilla-2.10.8-x86_64-2")

fix1 <- c("ConsoleKit2", "Cython", "GConf", "LibRaw", "M2Crypto", "MPlayer", 
      "ModemManager", "NetworkManager", "PyQt", "QScintilla", "Thunar", 
      "a2ps", "a52dec", "aaa_base", "aaa_elflibs", "aaa_terminfo", 
      "aalib", "acct", "acl", "acpid", "adwaita-icon-theme", "akonadi", 
      "alpine", "alsa-lib", "alsa-oss", "alsa-plugins", "alsa-utils", 
      "amarok", "amor", "amp")

ser2 <- function(in1, ... ) {
  out1 = NULL  #output
  l1 <- hd1 #list of all files
  for (i in 1:length(in1 )) {
    dec1 = l1[which(grepl(in1[i], l1))][1]  #start to filter the main list by list of dupes
    dec2 = l1[which(grepl(in1[i], l1))][2]
  }
  return(list(dec1, dec2))
}

ser2(fix1)
```

I get `list(NA, NA)`. That is because you keep overwriting the same `dec1` and `dec2` for every value of `in1`. So the return value is only giving you the matches for `amp`, which is not found in `hd1`.

I think what you are trying to accomplish in this function would be better done with:

```
lapply(fix1, grep, hd1, value = TRUE)
```

What that does is run `grep(fix1[i], hd1, value = TRUE)` for all `i` values of `fix1`, and sticks them in a list.

Assuming that `hd1` is sorted in earliest to latest order, you could get the latest of each by value by using `tail`.

```
matches <- lapply(fix1, grep, hd1, value = TRUE)
unlist(lapply(matches, tail, 1))
# [1] "ConsoleKit2-1.0.0-x86_64-4"    "Cython-0.29.12-x86_64-1"      
# [3] "GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-4"          "LibRaw-0.18.12-x86_64-1"      
# [5] "M2Crypto-0.35.2-x86_64-1"      "MPlayer-20190418-x86_64-1"    
# [7] "ModemManager-1.4.14-x86_64-1"  "NetworkManager-1.2.2-x86_64-2"
# [9] "PyQt-4.12.1-x86_64-3"          "QScintilla-2.10.8-x86_64-2"
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The comment from NpT helped me figure out what was going wrong: a couple of NAs were there that I did not realize were in there. However, your suggestion with the last two lines of code helps a lot. `hd1` is not sorted from earliest to latest. So the code that I left out (some if/else and ">" and a couple more lines) was supposed to break out the version/date info and pick from there.